# How to add < and > in android strings.xml

Tags: android

I need to add `<string name="name_hint"><Given Name></string>` in strings.xml. What is the escape sequence in order to do that? The string to be added is `<Given Name>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `&lt;` for less than symbol and `&gt;` for greater than symbol.
so here you need to replace like:

```
<string name="name_hint">&lt;Given Name&gt;</string>
```

Answer (score 30):

The Android string.xml file is just a regular XML file, so you can use the XML escape characters:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Your example would become `<string name="name_hint">&lt;Given Name&gt;</string>`

**UPDATE:**
Furthermore you can use the [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) of each character, a blank space is for example `&#032;`, and a non-breaking space is `&#160;`.

Note that I am not entirely sure whether this is officially supported by the XML standards, or that it 'just works'...

Comment: very true. SO is awesome!

Comment: What is it or blank space. Say `<string name="name_hint">&lt;Given Name&gt;&lt;Middle&gt;&lt;Surname&gt; </string>` If I need 5 spaces before Middle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`
So you should add the following string in your app's strings.xml like:

```
<string name="name_hint">&lt;Given Name&gt;</string>
```

For your another requirement you can define it like

<Given name> <Middlename> <Sirname>

```
<string name="name_hint">&lt;Given Name&gt; &lt;Middle Name&gt; &lt;Last Name&gt; </string>
```

or define three different strings.

```
<string name="name_hint1">&lt;Given Name&gt;</string>
<string name="name_hint2">&lt;Middle Name&gt;</string>
<string name="name_hint3">&lt;Last Name&gt;</string>
```

in your java file add it dynamically

```
tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.name_hint1) + "  " +
  getResources().getString(R.string.name_hint2)+"  " + 
  getResources().getString(R.string.name_hint3));
```

Comment: What if , it is something like <Given name>   <Middlename>   <Sirname>   - ie; 3 blankspace between each of them

Comment: That approach of putting space will not work. I tried it before posting

Comment: It is working my side but  if it is not working there you can try my last edited code. You can define three different strings and can add them through your activity class. Here you can add as much space between the strings as you want.